# Is $W$ a subspace of $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question is given below:

> [image]

My questions are:

1-I do not understand the second constituent of $W$, what is the difference between it and the first constituent? could anyone explain this to me, please? It would be spectacular if the explanation is with an example.

2-Also, what is the field upon which this vector space is defined?

Because I do not know the answers to the above I am unable to answer the question, so any help in answering the main question will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "constituent"? $W$ is a space of functions : what do you mean by "first" and "second" constituent? Also, the underlying field is likely to be $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I mean component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1-I do not understand the second constituent of $W$, what is the difference between it and the first constituent? could anyone explain this to me, please? It would be spectacular if the explanation is with an example.

Constant function $x\mapsto 0$ is just one, concrete, precisely defined function.

On the other hand there are many functions $f$ that satisfy "$f(a)=0$ for at most finitely many $a$". For starters the constant function $x\mapsto 0$ does not satisfy it (it has infinitely many zeros, in fact all args are zeros). An example would be $f(x)=x$ which attains $0$ only at $x=0$ or $f(x)=x^2-1$ which has two zeros: $-1$ and $1$. So in particular all polynomials (except for constant $0$) satisfy the condition. But there are of course other functions.

A counterexample is $f(x)=\sin(x)$ which has infinitely many zeros (at $k\pi$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$) so it is not in $W$.

> 2-Also, what is the field upon which this vector space is defined?

This isn't explicitely stated so we can't know for sure. But it's highly probable that the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$. Your $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ as follows: if $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f\in V$ then $rf$ is a function defined by $(rf)(x)=rf(x)$. The right side is just real numbers multiplication. This is also known as the pointwise scalar multiplication. That's what a typical mathematician sees when you talk about $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ being a vector space.

Also note that the vector addition on $V$ is not explicitely defined as well. But again we can assume that it is the standard, pointwise addition: $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

I would like first to explain the question to you. We have a set $V=(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}})$ of all real-valued functions with domain $\mathbb{R}$. Clearly $V$ forms a vector space over the field $\mathbb{R}$ (by default). Now $W$ be a subset of $V$ containing the $0_\mathbb{R}$(where $0_\mathbb{R}(x)=0, \forall~ x\in \
\mathbb{R}$ ) function and all such functions $f$ which gives output $0$ only for some finite elements of $\mathbb{R}$. Then we have to check whether $W$ is a subspace of $V$ or not.

The answer is not, for considering the two function $f,g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $g(x)=x, \forall x\in \mathbb{R/Q}$ then clearly $f,g \in W$ but $f+g$ does not belongs to $W$. Therefore $W$ is not be a subspace of $V$.

Comment: So what is the importance of the constant function $0_{\mathbb{R}}$ in $W$? we did not use it in our example.

Comment: @hopefully, you have used it. Read the exercise carefully, what is written? A  constant function that maps $x\longmapsto 0$ is the additive identity $0_\mathbb{R}$ of the vector space $V$. I used it precisely to explain better about the additive identity of the vector space. Now in order to check whether $W$ is a subspace of $V$ or not, if the $0_\mathbb{R}$ will be not in $W$, then the exercise becomes so obvious since the additive identity will be not present in $W$, it can not become a subspace. Therefore to make it tedious they used this.

Answer (score 2):

The meanings of the terms have been explained in the other answer. If $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ and $g(x)=-1$ for all $x$ except one point $x_0$ where $g(x_0)=1$ then  $f$ and $g$ are in $W$ but $f+g$ is not in $W$. Hence $W$ is not a vector space.

Comment: W is not a subspace of V.

Comment: @MANISHANKARPANDEY Thank you. I meant $W$ whey I wrote $V$.

Comment: I do not understand why you $f,g$ are in $W$? Is not all functions in $W$ has image 0?

Comment: No. When you say that a set is at most finite you allow that set to be empty. The set of points $a$ with $f(a)=0$ may be empty. @hopefully

Answer (score 1):

Here's a counterexample using only continuous functions:

Take $f = (x\mapsto x+\sin(x))$ and $g=(x\mapsto -x)$. Clearly both functions are in $W$. However the sum of both functions is the sine function, which is not in $W$.